# Juggling HP Server and VMWare Compatibility for Ext SAS

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp-proliant, sas

We operate a set of standalone HP DL360 servers to run our plant control system and are now implementing an upgrade to a vSphere 6.0 (Essentials Plus) approach.
The upgraded system will be a pair of new DL380 Gen9 servers and a re-use of one of the DL360 G7 servers.
The re-use of the DL360 G7 is where the confusion starts.  I am hoping to implement this as the third vSphere host for the non-vMotion virtual servers as none of these are going to be very demanding loads.  One of these virtual servers will be a backup server with a LTO-5 or LTO-6 tape library that I am proposing to implement as pass-through.

Now to the issue I am grappling with - I understand that I need to meet two main requirements for compatibility of the SAS HBA for the tape drive interfacing:

1. Compatibility of the HBA with vSphere 6.0
2. Compatibility of the HBA with the DL360 G7 server

The original parts listed as compatible in the DL360 G7 documentation are not easily sourced and not great value in my country, but I can get them.  However none of these seem to be listed as compatible with vSphere 6.0 (the DL360 G7 itself is listed as compatible).

Candidates that I looked at were:

HP 462828-B21 HP Smart Array P212/ZM 1-ports Int/1-ports Ext PCIe x8 SAS Controller

HP 462834-B21 HP Smart Array P212/256 1-ports Int/1-ports Ext PCIe x8 SAS Controller

HP 614988-B21 HP Modular Smart Array SC08e 2-ports Ext PCIe x8 SAS Host Bus Adapter

The SC08e is not listed as compatible with 6.0 but the P212 seems to be until you drill down in:
[P212 VMWare Compatibility](https://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/detail.php?deviceCategory=io&productid=4617&deviceCategory=io&details=1&partner=41&releases=275,274,273&keyword=SAS&page=2&display_interval=10&sortColumn=Partner&sortOrder=Asc)
and then it seems to be pointing to a vSphere 5.5 driver set (hpsa version 5.5.0.118-1OEM)?  The 6.0 one says "NA".

Maybe I am not understanding the compatibility thing correctly.  Can anyone shed some useful experience in whether this is going to be a "supported" approach?  Should I dump the HP option and go with a third-party option suggested by the tape library supplier?

Answer (score 0):

HPE Customized ESXi Image supports most (if not all) HP server hardware.
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/servers/solutions.html?compURI=1499005#tab=TAB4
http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c04430318
N/A means minimum firmware version. Maybe that driver supports all firmware versions. In any case Smart Array P212 surely compatible with vSphere 6.0u2
All you need is to install HPE Customized ESXi Image instead of common ESXi image provided on Vmware site.

Comment: OK - had a read through some of the *many* docs that HP have for this and it makes a bit more sense now.  Thanks for pointing me to this.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to skip SAS passthrough. It's not a great approach if you need to run your backup tape drive from an ESXi host.

However, you can also use SCSI/SAS devices natively without going through the passthrough steps. I've done this quite a bit in the past. Attach the drive and try "Adding a SCSI device" to the VM in question.

My controller recommendations depend on the drive. Either controller works. The P212 will use an HPSA driver. The HP H221 or H222 external SAS adapters use an LSI driver. But it's best to go with the recommendation for the actual drive (which should be the H222). Neither of these drivers are in danger with ESXi 6.0.

Comment: The passthrough option was a suggestion from one of the products I have been considering (Strongbox VA  which is a tape-as-NAS type product).  Another vendor has indicated that their tape-as-NAS software requires it's own standalone hardware with Suse installed to allow installation of their software (LTFStor AKA ValueStor) - when I asked if I could install Suse and their software as a VM they said no, but I am wondering how hard that could be?

Comment: What  other vendors are in that space? I hadn't heard of Strongbox before.

Comment: There are quite a few vendors for the Tape-As-NAS concept but my system is looking for a solution based on a budget of maybe A$8K for the tape library (2 tape drives, min 8 slots) plus maybe A$5K for the software solution (installed on a standalone "spare" server or as a VM on the new vSphere hosts.  This has narrowed it down to the Strongbox VM solution and the LTFStor/ValueStor options.  More expensive options include Quantum Scalar LTFS Appliance and a HPStoreEver/QStar Archive Manager solution.